# как сделать такое же пролистываемое меню пайтон телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Получил задание от заказчика на доработку бота, попросил сделать меню как на скрине, как мне это сделать? Через WebApp?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: про inline ботов можете почитать в [офф. документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inline-mode)